# drag and drop text in sublime text (build 4126)

Tags: sublimetext

I would like to select text and then able to drag that text to another part of the page. Currently, I can select text but can't then move it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can hold Ctrl + drag, this way you will be able to do that!